# Character movement overwrites collider in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a FPS character and a sphere.
I've put walls around the character which follow to position of the character, so that the player is always in a small tube, surrounded by walls:

```
void Update () {
    Vector3 innerWalls = gameObject.transform.position;
    Vector3 player = GameObject.Find ("playerController").transform.position;
    Vector3 temp;
    temp.x = player.x;
    temp.z = player.z;
    temp.y = innerWalls.y;
    gameObject.transform.position = temp;
}
```

Next, I've disabled the mesh renderer so that the walls are invisible for the player.

The reason I've done this, is because I want to maintain a certain distance between my sphere and the player. If the player would go to near of the sphere, the sphere would hit the walls and the player should be able to "move" to sphere (basically the walls should be pushing it forward).

This doesn't work, unfortunately. After some flickering, the sphere passes through the walls. If I would make the sphere move, it's unable to go through walls be itself, but when the player is moving the walls, apparently it is.

Anyone knows what's causing this issue or knows how to fix this?

Edit: I think this is not a duplicate question. My question is not about moving a RigidBody. My character moves, using `CharacterController.Move`, but that's not relevant for the question. The question is about the walls (which don't have a rigidbody) not being able to collide with the sphere (which has a rigidbody but doesn't move).

Comment: Also does walls or sphere have rigidbody?

Comment: I'm using a rigidbody on the sphere, but I disabled gravity on it because it floats in the air. I'm not using a rigidbody on the walls, only a collider. I tried adding a rigidbody to the walls too, but that makes the walls tip and possibly fall over after hitting the sphere. If you choose to Freeze the rotation of the walls, the sphere again passes through the walls.